# Solid State in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook

I am in the market for a new MBP.  I am leaning towards the 13 inch for its portability.  I am considering the 128 Solid state drive; however have heard rumors that Mac uses a crappy brand which is not worth the $360 add on price.  Does anyone know the Brand of SSD Mac uses, and if you would buy this or put out a little more money on an Intel drive (and install it yourself).
Additionally, if I was to try and install it and something went wrong with the computer in the future, have I voided my year warranty?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the question you should be asking yourself is what's more important? Space or speed?  You have to remember that for most purposes you will barely notice a solid state drives boost.  Only if you're loading large files on a regular basis.

That being said, I find even a 160 gb hard drive to be small because I take some pictures and occasionally record a song on garage band.

Unless you think that the speed boost is important (and with a macbook pro, I don't think it is.  I go from hibernated to running in 3 seconds) I'd spend that money on a bigger drive

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some of the other answers, running OS X on flash makes a huge difference to the speed of the machine; application launch times go down a LOT, due to the 1000x better seek time of the flash.  But it is still all about speed vs space and whether the tradeoff is worth the money; hence my machine has a hard drive.

I expect the next iteration of the MacBook Pro to have both flash *and* a hard drive in some configurations, and that would be the ideal; put the system on flash and your data on disc.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=588540) suggests they're Samsung drives.

Apple tends to be pretty careful about what they put in their systems, as bad hardware would hurt the premium image they've built for their brands.

Answer (score 0):

Throughout the lifetime of a model, Apple does occasionally change OEMs. They might use Samsung today and someone else tomorrow.

Given the rapid evolution in solid state drives, the fact that they're apparently making an announcement January 27, and the age of the current MacBook line, I would wait until the second week of February. It may not be anything major on the MacBook side, but there might be price adjustments or something.

And given that they publish [instructions for replacing the drive](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MBPRO_13inch_Mid2009_Hard_Drive_DIY.pdf) that caution against damage that may void your warranty, it would seem that the mere act of replacing the drive does not.